# How i can set Desktop Icon of my java Application in windows7, 8?

Tags: java, image, icons, desktop

I have here nice and working code

```
InputStream img = Main.class.getResourcesAsStream("/optician/icon.png");
BufferedImage myImg=ImageIO.read(img);
setIconImage(myImg);
```

and here is also try/catch but i did not write this. So, this is working fine anywhere, in JFrame, in taskbar, everywhere is working fine but in my Desktop is again Java coffee cup, it is not changed with this code. Any idea how i can change Desktop Icon ? I can't find any solution...

Comment: Look at `Launch4J` you can create an executable file out of a java jar file and you can specify an icon...

Comment: where is this file placed ?

Comment: If u think about this PNG file, it is placed in package of my project and i made runnable .jar file. so i called it as ResourceStream to read it from package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operating systems assign icons based on file associations. Because your code is compiled to a jar, the OS is going to give it the icon it gives to all jar files.

To give your application a custom icon, you have to compile it to an executable or use an executable to launch the jar. If the OS knows that a file is an executable, it will check to see if it supplies an icon in its binary, and if it doesn't, it will give it the default icon.

There are numerous third party programs that can make executables out of jars. You can search using your favorite search engine to find a suitable program (something along the lines of "jar to executable" or "jar to exe")

Comment: HI i did it from Launch4J and i did the job, i made .exe from .jar and it is work fine. BUt i have when i plant image there, i did it with 32x32, 64x64 and higher and every picture ( .ico ) when i create .exe file is a bad quality, i dont know why and how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

For **Java coffee cup icon** change you can use below code

```
public class StuInfo extends JFrame {

Container cont;

StuInfo() {
    setIconImage(new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(
            "images/LOGO000.gif")).getImage());
    setLayout(null);
    cont = getContentPane();
    cont.setLayout(null);
    cont.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 600);
    setSize(600, 500);
    setVisible(true);

 }

public static void main(String args[]) {
    StuInfo s = new StuInfo();
    s.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
 }
```

Comment: This did not help, it works also fine and i can see my img in JFrame in left corner, in taskmenu, everywhere, but on desktop is still java coffee cup.
I found solution trought Launch4J but every picture when i get from that it make bad quality when i convert to .exe